# Is there a way of creating multiple possible subject lines in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

Currently, I am able to create 2 possible subject lines. For example:

```
%%[IF title=="Mr." THEN]%%Happy Holidays Mr.%%familyName%% from the Team!%%[ELSE]%%Happy Holidays %%givenName%% from the the Team!%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Is there a way to create 4 possible subjects lines like if:

```
%%[IF title=="Mr." language==“en”]%%.....%%[IF title=="Mr." language=="fr"]%% ....%%[IF language == "fr"]%% ....%%[ELSE]%%....%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Did you try nesting? %%[IF title=="Mr." THEN]%%Happy Holidays Mr.%%familyName%% from the Team!%%[ELSE]%% %%[IF title=="Ms." THEN]%%Happy Holidays Ms.%%familyName%% from the Team!%%[ELSE]%%Happy Holidays %%givenName%% from the the Team!%%[ENDIF]%% %%[ENDIF]%%

Comment: That wouldn't work as Mr is the only title we have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is correct in your question, you just need to format it right and use ELSEIF statements:

```
%%[
SET @Title = AttributeValue(title)
SET @language = AttributeValue(language)

IF @Title=="Mr." AND @Language==“en” THEN
    SET @Subject = "Subject 1"
ELSEIF @Title=="Mr." AND @Language=="fr" THEN
    SET @Subject = "Subject 2"
ELSEIF @Language == "fr" THEN
    SET @Subject = "Subject 3"
ELSE
    SET @Subject = "Subject 4"
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@Subject)=%%
```

You also can push the script into the email and just have the subject be '%%=v(@Subject)=%%' as the email body is compiled prior to the subject line, so the variable will be filled.

If you still want to directly print out the subjects instead of an AMPScript variable, you can do the following:

```
%%[
SET @Title = AttributeValue(title)
SET @language = AttributeValue(language)

IF @Title=="Mr." AND @Language==“en” THEN]%%
    Subject 1
%%[ELSEIF @Title=="Mr." AND @Language=="fr" THEN]%%
    Subject 2
%%[ELSEIF @Language == "fr" THEN]%%
    Subject 3
%%[ELSE]%%
    Subject 4
%%[ENDIF]%%
```